# ¿Múltiples constructores para clase que extiende de SwingWorker?

Tags: java

Mientras hago una consulta a la base de datos (BD), un programa Java se tarda 1 ó 2 segundos al menos. Quiero mostrar un gif animado durante ese tiempo. Ya logré mi objetivo usando la clase [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) siguiendo [este tutorial](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplo_sencillo_con_SwingWorker%20package%20helpers;).

Este es mi código:

```
package mipackage;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Spinner extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    public JFrame ventanaActual;
    public JLabel gifAnimado;
    public String usuario;
    public String contrasena;

    // Constructor 1
    public Spinner(JFrame ventanaActual, JLabel gifAnimado, String usuario, String contrasena) {
        this.ventanaActual = ventanaActual;
        this.gifAnimado = gifAnimado;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        gifAnimado.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/loading-7.gif")));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        gifAnimado.setIcon(null);
    }
}
```

Resulta que acabo de añadir otra sección en mi programa Java que hace otra consulta a la BD totalmente diferente. Claramente quiero implementar el mismo GIF animado para esta otra consulta.

La pregunta es: ¿cómo modificar el código para que sirva en todas las secciones donde hago queries a la BD?

No he encontrado nada online que me dé respuesta a esto. Y lo único que se me ocurrió, no funciona, a saber, crear múltiples constructores. Por tanto, añadí este otro:

```
// Constructor 2
public Spinner(JButton boton, JLabel gifAnimado, String nombre, String apellido1, String apellido2, String email) {
    this.boton = boton;
    this.gifAnimado = gifAnimado;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido1 = apellido1;
    this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Y si bien añadir múltiples constructores no causa ningún error, es cierto también que no funciona (sólo funciona el 1er constructor). ¿Alguna idea de cómo lograr mi objetivo?

Answer (score 1):

No creo que la animación deba estar en el SwingWorker en si.  SwingWorker tiene tres estados

```
SwingWorker.StateValue.PENDING // Cuando se construye el SwingWorker
SwingWorker.StateValue.STARTED // Cuando acaba de iniciar, antes de invocar doInBackground()
SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE    // Cuando terminó.
```

Entonces puedes manejar tu animación escuchando el estado del SwingWorker. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Animacion implements java.beans.PropertyChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evento) {
        if ("state".equals(evento.getPropertyName())) {
            // aquí recibimos notificación del worker que cambió de estado.
            SwingWorker.StateValue estado = (SwingWorker.StateValue)evento.getNewValue();
            switch (estado) {
                case STARTED: //El worker ha iniciado
                   ///AQUÍ MOSTRAMOS LA ANIMACIÓN
                   gifAnimado.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/loading-7.gif")));
                   break;
                case DONE: // El worker ha terminado.
                   ///dejamos de escuchar al worker
                   SwingWorker worker = (SwingWorker)evento.getSource();
                   worker.removePropertyChangeListener(this);
                   ///y quitamos la animación 
                   gifAnimado.setIcon(null);
                   break;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Entonces cuando quieras implementar esa animación que pudieras tener constructores para que fueran diferentes tipos de animaciónes, etc. Solo tendrías que hacer:

```
SwingWorker worker = MiWorker();
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new Animacion());
worker.execute();
```

Entonces puedes usar tu animación para cualquier SwingWorker.

```
SwingWorker worker = MiOtroWorker();
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new Animacion());
worker.execute();
```

Agrego que dentro del método doInBackground() del SwingWorker yo solo tendría lo referente a la base de datos. O sea, la consulta de base de datos que mencionas. Ya que SwingWorker corre en teoría en un hilo (thread) diferente al EventThread (único hilo donde se deben accesar y manipular componentes swing). Por lo que yo  no tocaría ningún componente swing dentro de ese método.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @AlbertoLopez, por tu respuesta. Lamentablemente no he podido implementar tu código, ya que me saltan algunos errores que no pude corregir, como el de **removePropertyChangeListener** (que no existe tal método).

Comment: @GeorgeBerkeley ya edité mi respuesta. Cuando la puse anteriormente no tendía donde probarlo. Espero la puedas probar.

Comment: Muy bien, ya todo se ve mucho más claro. Perdón pero no logro entender esta línea: **SwingWorker worker = MiWorker()**. Netbeans me marca error aquí, me dice que no existe tal método (MiWorker). ¿Dónde debería crear ese método y en teoría qué debería contener?

Comment: MiWorker es una clase que vas a hacer que va extender SwingWorker que va por ejemplo a consultar una base de datos. Deberías tener un swingWorker para consultar la base de datos.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ha sido de mucha ayuda!